# I keep getting a ModuleNotFoundError in pycharm ;already installed 'openpyxl' with pip. No spelling/case errors. Module displayed in orange not grey

Tags: python, pycharm

I already installed the Module openpyxl using pip but it still gives me the errors. There are no spelling or case errors. On both the Windows and Pycharm terminals, it states that openpyxl is already satisfied. Unlike other modules /packages, it displays in orange color instead of grey showing contrast.

PS C:\Users\GARETH TIROP\PycharmProjects\pythonProjectone> pip3 install openpyxl
Collecting openpyxl
Using cached openpyxl-3.0.10-py2.py3-none-any.whl (242 kB)
Requirement already satisfied: et-xmlfile in c:\users\gareth tirop\appdata\local\programs\python\python310\lib\site-packages (from openpyxl) (1.1.0)
Installing collected packages: openpyxl
Successfully installed openpyxl-3.0.10
PS C:\Users\GARETH TIROP\PycharmProjects\pythonProjectone>

Answer (score 0):

To solve ModuleNotFoundError...go check on Youtube , an account @RISHABH MISHRA...All the help is there.

STEPS:FOR PYCHARM IDE users

1. click 'file' and 'close project'
2. It brings a new prompt...select 'new project'
3. Select the icon...'inherit site packages' then 'create' at the right end to finish up.
4. This will fix the ModuleNotFoundError' for an already installed module that,N/B: has no spelling/case errors.

The procedure works and has fixed my issue.